# HTTP Response differs depending on whether request is local or remote

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

If I make the request locally (POST [http://localhost:8790/blah/]) I get the following response header:

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  32
Content-Type    application/json
Date    Tue, 19 Mar 2013 13:59:34 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

If I make the request remotely (POST [http://123.456.1789:8790/blah/]) I get the following response header:

```
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  11
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 19 Mar 2013 14:08:40 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version 4.0
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
```

The POST parameters are quite superficial: name=value1&name2=value2

As you can see the content-type differs and as a result the data returned differs.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

EDIT
Local Request

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  36
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  blah=blah;
Host    localhost:8790
Pragma  no-cache
Referer [http://localhost:8790/blah/]
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Remote Request

```
Accept  application/json
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  36
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  blah=blah;
Host    123.456.1789:8790
Pragma  no-cache
Referer [http://123.456.1789:8790/blah/]
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Can we see any code? Are you using the same parameters on both requests?

Comment: Can we see the Request headers as well?

Comment: I've added the requests to my original question, but I have had to sanitize the data. Also I am using exactly the same parameters on both requests